# Save Chart Created In Image List

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, image, imagelist

I have created charts dynamically but I want to save chart created in image list or any other types of lists, as long as is not in folder.

**Question: How to save chart created in image list/other type of list?**

This is my codes:

```
                        Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
                        Chart1.DataSource = dt;
                        Chart1.Width = 800;
                        Chart1.Height = 500;

                        Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
                        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;

                        List<object> List_CHART = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["TITLE"], new object[] { row["MIN"], row["MAX"], row["25TH_PERCENTILE"], row["75TH_PERCENTILE"], row["50TH_PERCENTILE"], row["AVG"] });
                        }

                        //create chartareas
                        ChartArea ca= new ChartArea();
                        ca.AxisX = new Axis();
                        ca.AxisY = new Axis();
                        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

                        //databind
                        Chart1.DataBind();
                        Chart1.Visible = true;

                        panel.Controls.Add(Chart1);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at Chart API to find [Chart.SaveImage Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456143(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Google 'save Chart to stream' to find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582608/how-may-i-get-the-image-of-datavisualization-charting-chart-to-itextsharp-text-i).
3. Look at Image API [Image.FromStream Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx)

The final solution should look something like this:

```
        var chartImages = new ImageList();
        var chartStream = new MemoryStream()
        chart.SaveImage(chartStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        var chartImage = Image.FromStream(chartStream);
        chartImages.Add(chartImage);
```

Also, Pay attention to **Remarks** section on Image class:

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

Comment: hi @DanielS, I need the chart image instead of chart data because I want to store many chart images inside the image list, then later on export them to excel.